# PySpark weird behaviour of to_timestamp()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am noticing a bit weird behaviour in PySpark's (and possibly Spark's) `to_timestamp` function. Looks like it is converting some strings to timestamp correctly while some other strings of the exact same format to `null`. Consider the following example I worked out:

```py
times = [['2030-03-10 02:56:07'], ['2030-03-11 02:56:07']]

df_test = spark.createDataFrame(times, schema=StructType([
    StructField("time_string", StringType())
]))
df_test = df_test.withColumn('timestamp', 
                             F.to_timestamp('time_string', 
                                            format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
df_test.show(2, False)
```

This is what I get:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|time_string        |timestamp          |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2030-03-10 02:56:07|null               |
|2030-03-11 02:56:07|2030-03-11 02:56:07|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

What's the reason behind the second string being converted correctly but not the first one? I have tried with `unix_timestamp()` function as well and the result is the same.

Further strangely, if I don't use the `format` parameter, I don't get the `null` anymore but the timestamp's hour is incremented by one.

```py
df_test2 = df_test.withColumn('timestamp', F.to_timestamp('time_string'))
df_test2.show(2, False)
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|time_string        |timestamp          |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2030-03-10 02:56:07|2030-03-10 03:56:07|
|2030-03-11 02:56:07|2030-03-11 02:56:07|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Any idea what's going on?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried with in Scala as well via `spark-shell` and the result is the same:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

val times = Seq(Row("2030-03-10 02:56:07"), Row("2030-03-11 02:56:07"))
val schema=List((StructField("time_string", StringType)))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(times), 
                               StructType(schema))
val df_test = df.withColumn("timestamp", 
                      functions.to_timestamp(functions.col("time_string"), 
                                             fmt="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

df_test.show()
```

And the result:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|        time_string|          timestamp|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2030-03-10 02:56:07|               null|
|2030-03-11 02:56:07|2030-03-11 02:56:07|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: As far as I can tell not reproducible in 2.3.2 and 2.4.0.

Comment: @user10465355 I am using PySpark 2.4.0 as well. Are you using PySpark or scala?

Comment: PySpark shell, official binaries, default configuration, code pasted as-is (with imports `from pyspark.sql.types import *` and `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`).